# Why can't connect MySQL with Java in local network using XAMPP

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to connect MySQL with Java in a local network (between 3 computers) using XAMPP. But I can't do that with Java and tried to connect the database with PHP application, then connected. I think this is not XAMPP error. It may be in Java app.

My code:

```
Connection getcon() throws Exception {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101/checker";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    //Connection
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
    return con;
}
```

Exception:

> run: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link
>   failure due to underlying exception:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.net.SocketException MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection timed out: connect
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed
>   out: connect  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:276)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2666)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1531)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   connectionchecker.JDBC.getcon(JDBC.java:45)   at
>   connectionchecker.JDBC.getdata(JDBC.java:68)  at
>   connectionchecker.Check.incremntno(Check.java:28)     at
>   connectionchecker.Check.jButton1ActionPerformed(Check.java:84)    at
>   connectionchecker.Check.access$000(Check.java:15)     at
>   connectionchecker.Check$1.actionPerformed(Check.java:50)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6522)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6287)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4878)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4700)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4872)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4528)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4457)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2724)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4700)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:743)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:713)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:220)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:135)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:123)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:119)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:111)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> last packet sent to the server was 43 ms ago. my msg is conn ok
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

JDBC class:

```
public class JDBC {

    private static JDBC j;
    Connection con = null;

    private JDBC() {

    }

    public static JDBC getJDBC() {
        if(j == null){
            j= new JDBC();
        }
        return j;
    }

      Connection getcon() throws Exception {

          try {
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/checker";
        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101:80/checker";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";
        //Connection
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);

          } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
              System.out.println(e);
          }

      return con;
    }

    void setdata(String sql) {
        try {
             if (con == null) {
                getcon();
            }
            con.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    ResultSet getdata(String sql) throws Exception {
        if (con == null) {
            getcon();
            System.out.println("my msg is conn ok");
        }else{
            System.out.println("my msg is conn not ok");
        }
        ResultSet rset = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
        return rset;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to share exception, error, so that we can understand the reason to help you

Comment: Dear sir, now I have added. but not error for me to identify.  thank you.

Comment: @LakmalBodhinayaka did you got the solution? if yes can you please share?

Comment: @Shahina really sorry, I didn't got any solution with relatively this question. but I found another way, so I have used PHP (PHP desktop). So I know that is not correct way but enough for that situation. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the port number of the XAMPP after the ip address.

The default port number is 80 for XAMPP.

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101:80/checker";
```

Or try this one below

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101:8080/checker";
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies here

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101:80/checker";
```

Note, this should represent your db server and port where your db is running. Above url is wrong as, port `80` is default port number for Apache server. But, you need to use mysql port, which is 3306 (default).

Instead, you should try

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.101:3306/checker";
```

I'm assuming `checker` is database name.